# encrypt object in aws s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, encryption, amazon-s3

I am saving some images/objects in aws s3 bucket from my application. First i am getting signed url from nodejs service api and uploading images or files to singed url using jquery ajax. I can open image or object using the link provided in the properties (https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/objectname).

I want to provide security for each uploaded object. Even by chance if any anonymous user gets the link (https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/objectname) somewhere he should  not be able to open it. They (objects) should be accessed and open only cases like when request has some headers key values etc.  I tried server side encryption by specifying header key values in request as shown below.

```
        var file = document.getElementById('fileupload').files[0];
        $.ajax({
            url: signedurl,
            type: "PUT",
            data: file,
            header:{'x-amz-server-side-encryption':'AES256'},               
            contentType: file.type,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                var res = result;

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
```

Doesn't sever side encryption keep encrypted object on s3 bucket storage? Does it only encrypts while transferring and decrypts before saving on s3 storage?

If it stores encrypted object on s3 storage then how can i open it using the link shown in properties.

Answer (score 2):

**Server-Side Encryption (SSE)** in Amazon S3 encrypts objects *at rest* (stored on disk) but decrypts objects when they are retrieved. Therefore, it is a transparent form of encryption.

If you wish to keep objects in Amazon S3 private, but make them available to specific authorized users, I would recommend using **Pre-Signed URLs**.

This works by having your application generate a URL that provides time-limited access to a specific object in Amazon S3. The objects are otherwise kept private so they are not accessible.

See documentation: [Share an Object with Others](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Comment: I made the object private by unchecking open/download and view permissions properties of object but still i can open/view object with the link (https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/objectname). I guess i have to encrypt file on client side and store it on s3 . So any user or even the owner of s3 couldn't view/open objects despite having the object link. They should retrieve object from s3 and decrypt it with private key.

Comment: The ability to access an object in Amazon S3 is totally independent of encryption. Let's focus on access. It is possible that your object was cached by your browser, so try opening it in another browser or on another computer. It should return "Access Denied". If it is still accessible, then you might have a Bucket Policy in effect that is granting the access. The first step is to get your objects private again, and then play with methods of granting access. Also make sure you're opening the object by clicking the link in **Properties** rather than using the **Open** command.